# Print out sequences line by line from a binary file

Tags: c, file, malloc

Read from a binary file. I was asked to find out sequences of more than 4 characters and print out one sequence per line. check is a function to check if the character is printable. But my program keeps printing out a full new line between sequences and sometimes it prints out sequences that are only 3 characters long. size is the file size, start and end indicate the sequence's first character's index and the last character's index.The following is part of my code:

```
char* buffer = malloc(size);
fread(buffer, size, 1, file);   
while (end + 1 <= size){
    while(check(buffer[end]) == 1){
        end++;
    }
    if ((end - start + 1 ) >= 4){
        printf("%.*s\n", end - start + 1, &buffer[start]);
    }
    end++;
    start = end;
}
free(buffer);
fclose(file);

int check(char char){
if ((char >= 32)&&(char <= 126))
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, please [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you still can figure out your problem, then please edit your question to elaborate on what the problem is, and include information that you collected while debugging. Also please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And of course, don't forget to actually *ask* a question.

Comment: Do you initialize `start` and `end` to `0` before the loop?

Comment: yes, all set to 0 before the first while loop

Comment: Does your `check` consider `\n` a printable character?

Comment: My check function just simply returns 1 if the character is between 32 and 126 and returns 0 otherwise. So I think the new line character is not considered as printable in my function

Comment: Can you verify that your three letter sequences (which should be at least 4) not contain ` ` (space)?

Comment: I think you need to upgrade to a [mcve], including some sample input (probably better in hex representation), output and desired output.

Comment: They don't contain any space. I have lines like "tos" "map"

Answer (score 0):

You are operating with something like `printf("%20s")`, which expects 0-terminated strings as input. Note that `fread` will not add such a termination character; 
Further, the `20` denotes the minimum width and padding, but `printf` will never truncate a value. Hence, it will print until the (probably missing) end of the input string, probably exceeding buffer and yielding undefined behaviour.

I'd do the following:

```
char* buffer = malloc(size+1);
fread(buffer, size, 1, file);
buffer[size]='\0';  // to be sure that you come to an end

while (end + 1 <= size){
    while(check(buffer[end]) == 1){
        end++;
    }
    if ((end - start + 1 ) >= 4){
        buffer[end] = '\0'; // terminate the sequence
        printf("%s\n", &buffer[start]);
    }
    end++;
    start = end;
}
free(buffer);
fclose(file);
```

Comment: The only-three-letters sequences are explained by newlines beyond the intended part of the strings to output, right? Probably more than one of them.

Comment: Got rid of the new lines but still getting those 3-letter sequences

Comment: just added the check function

Comment: I'm not quite sure why. But I just tried to change to (end - start ) >= 4 and it seems like this works.

Comment: So I think I figured it out. I said the start and end to be indices but it's not quite right. It was at position 0 at the beginning, before there's anything in the sequence. Now I need to have a sequence that has >= 4 characters, so I should have the end-start = 4. The position 0 was not actually the first character in my sequence.